# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32 and my stored procedure is with the same parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I know that this problem is to much mentioned but problem is wasting my time, and in my stored procedure the parameters are the same, I don't know why this happens. I hope you can help me

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_InfoPacient";
    cmd.Connection = cn;

    SqlParameter pd = new SqlParameter("@PacientId",SqlDbType.Int);
    pd.Value = DropDownList1.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pd);

    SqlParameter pname = new SqlParameter("@EmriPacientit",SqlDbType.VarChar,20);
    pname.Value = TextBox12.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pname);

    SqlParameter age = new SqlParameter("@Mosha",SqlDbType.Int);
    age.Value = TextBox13.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(age);

    SqlParameter dep = new SqlParameter("@Departamenti", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    dep.Value = TextBox14.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(dep);

    SqlParameter doct = new SqlParameter("@DrPersonal", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    doct.Value = TextBox15.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(doct);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: change `age.Value = TextBox13.Text;` too

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like it boils down to these two lines:

```
> SqlParameter pd = new SqlParameter("@PacientId",SqlDbType.Int);
> pd.Value = DropDownList1.Text;
```

In the first line you're telling the command that parameter "PacientId" is of type `int`.

In the second line you're assigning the parameter the value of `DropDownList1.Text`, which will be of type `string`.

To solve this you probably need to `Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.Text)` to make sure the parameter value you set is an integer.

As Hogan points out, there is a potential issue if the Text value is *not* an integer - e.g. if you have values "1", "2", "3" and "Potato". You cannot parse "Panini" to an Int.
Use Int.TryParse when you're not absolutely certain your inputs will convert. The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) describes this well.

Comment: please add information about int.Parse() to finish this answer

Comment: Why would that be needed? `Convert.ToInt32` is an acceptable way to turn a `string` into an `int`.

Comment: Thank you,i thought that i solved it,but again the same problem,i deleted and created again the store procedure very focused,but i don't know